# UITableview covering button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I tried to make floating button on top of `uitableview`, I already set `uitableview` to back and the button is in the front on storyboard but when I run the application the table covering the button. How can I make the button to always on front?

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to bring your subviews on top of tableview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourButton];
}
```

Comment: it didn't work for me, the button still not going to front

Comment: turns out that your answer work for me, but I put the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Can you please change your answer so I can accept this answer

Comment: why you have to put button in cellForRowAtIndexPath? @EgaSetyaPutra

Comment: I dont know, it just didn't work if I put it in viewdidload

Comment: Try to put in viewwillappear than check @EgaSetyaPutra

Answer (score 0):

Set autoresizing mask of your buttons from bottom then check. If buttons are not appearing then add this code to in your `viewDidLoad` method -

```
[self.view bringSubViewToFront: btn_Cancel];
[self.view bringSubViewToFront: btn_Delete];
```